# Adding hardhat as a network on metamask error

Tags: blockchain, metamask, hardhat

```
New RPC Url: http://127.0.0.1:8545/
ChainId: 31337
Could not fetch chain ID. Is your RPC URL correct?
```

I am trying to run a local blockchain using hardhat but during configuration it is showing this error. I googled it and got this as the RPC url. Thanks for helping!

Comment: Do you have a `hardhat node` running in the background while trying to access it?

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your hardhat.config.js and then do npx hardhat node. After that it should not show any error in your metamask.

networks: {
hardhat: {
chainId: 1337
}
}